# Preserve indentation in xml transformation by msxml

Tags: xslt, msxml

I have an xml file and xsl for it.

When I execute the command

```
msxml input.xml input.xsl -o output.xml
```

my output.xml is without indentation. All nodes are in the same line. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Can you edit the XSLT? Then add

```
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
```

Here is a more complete example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">...</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: yes, I can. But wherever I will put it, I have an error that output is prohibited.

Comment: @user3050705, I have edited and shown where to put the `xsl:output`.

Comment: Thanks. the result is that nodes are in separated lines, but indent is still broken (all is aligned to left). Have you any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: @user3050705, I am not sure, I think msxml is a command line interface allowing to use different MSXML versions. Check its documentation or try `msxml -h` or `msxml -help` to find out whether you can select a specific MSXML version and then experiment to see whether a different version gives a better result. Or try a different XSLT processor, usually `<xsl:output indent="yes"/>` would give some readable indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, MSXML 6's idea of indentation is putting all lines at the same width. Setting indent to 'no' in your XSL file will result in a one-line file.